# Is Image Stitching and Image overlapping same concept?

Tags: opencv

I am working on a project, which will intake multiple images (lets say 2 for the moment) and combine them to generate a better image. The resultant image will be a combination of those input images. As a requirement I want to achieve this by using OpenCV. I read about Image Stitching and saw some example images in the process and now I am confused whether image overlapping is equal to image stitching, or can the Stitcher class in OpenCV do Image overlapping? A little clarity as to how can I achieve the above project problem thru OpenCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Image overlapping" is not really a term used in the CV literature. The general concept of matching images via transformations is most often called [image registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration). Image registration is taking many images and inserting them all into one shared coordinate system. Image stitching relies on that same function, but additionally concerns itself with how to blend multiple images. Furthermore, image stitching tries to take into account multiple images at once and makes small adjustments to the paired image registrations.

But it seems you're interested in producing higher quality images from multiple images of the same space (or from video feed of the space for example). The term for that is not image overlapping but *super-resolution*; specifically, super-resolution from multiple images. You'll want to look into specialized filters (after warping to the same coordinates) to combine those multiple views into a high resolution image. There are many papers on this topic ([e.g.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18092595)). Even mean or median filters (that is, taking the mean or median at every pixel location across the images) can work well, assuming your transformations are very good.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir , I took a quick look into Image registration and realized that this is what needs to be done. As I realized that Image stitching needs some similarity during the transition of the images to combine them into a one. But when tried to stitch 2 same image, it gives an error "cant stitch image". Dont know the reason for that. Thats not my problem anymore. I am quite novice in this, so i'll ask another question, do I have to abandon the whole concept of Stitching? Can I do Image registration via OpenCV?

Comment: Glad that you found what you were looking for! If my solution answered your question could you mark it as accepted? Thank you!